# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '@' in freecontactformsettings.php on line 3

Tags: php, parsing, syntax

Im in the process of making a website for my company and i'm getting an error with some php code.

```
<?php

$email_to = “myemail@gmail.com”; // your email address
$email_subject = "Contact Form Message"; // email subject line
$thankyou = "thankyou.htm"; // thank you page

// if you update the question on the form -
// you need to update the questions answer below
$antispam_answer = "25";

?>
```

The code was grabbed from online so im not too familiar with it, when I try to submit the form i've grabbed it throws up an error saying:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '@' in /home/a9670576/public_html/freecontactformsettings.php on line 3

What could be causing this? (Note: in the actual code "myemail@gmail.com" does have my actual email I just changed here for the purpose of asking the question)

Comment: Use `"` quotes - `$email_to = "myemail@gmail.com";` instead of `$email_to = “myemail@gmail.com”;`

Comment: @KrishR Sorry, I noticed your comment after I posted my answer.

Comment: Let's close the question, shall we? You've never accepted either answer. Mine being the first one, but that's not the issue here. The question is still considered unanswered.

Answer (score 7):

It's the curly quotes (*a.k.a. smart quotes*) in:

```
$email_to = “myemail@gmail.com”;
```

change it to:

```
$email_to = "myemail@gmail.com";
```

this may have been caused by copying code from a Website or from Windows Write or other form of type/word processor.

Answer (score 2):

The qutoes of your value is wrong use:

```
"myemail@gmail.com"
```

instead of:

```
“myemail@gmail.com”
```